# How to draw five start on react

Tags: css, reactjs

I need to draw the five-star on react component for rating.
The result would be something like that.
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate, what exactly you are trying to do? You need to render an SVG? Or you want to show 5 images? Or you want to show one image? Should it be interactive or just some presentation? What have you tried already that didn't work?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an SVG file and displaying that instead, since that's much simpler. You can have five elements with the SVG file as the background or 5 `img` tags, and give each one an ID to see what rating they clicked on.

You can also use a JavaScript function to make them change to a filled in version once someone hovers over a star.

Answer (score -1):

```css
    .five-point-star {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin: 12px 0;
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;
      border-right: 20px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 15px solid black;
      border-left: 15px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(37deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(37deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(37deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(37deg);
      transform: rotate(37deg);
    }
    
    .five-point-star:before {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      top: -9px;
      left: -12px;
      content: "";
      border-bottom: 12.3px solid green;
      border-left: 4.5px solid transparent;
      border-right: 4.5px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(323deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(323deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(323deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(323deg);
      transform: rotate(323deg);
    }
    
    .five-point-star:after {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;
      top: 0;
      left: -20px;
      content: "";
      border-right: 20px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 15px solid green;
      border-left: 20px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(286deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(286deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(286deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(286deg);
      transform: rotate(286deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="five-point-star"></div>
```